# What "approximation factor" means for approximation algorithms?

Tags: probability, approximation

The paper I read starts with the following text:

> One of the most appealing open problems in the graph streaming area (see Problem 60 in [1]) is to close the gap between the **approximation factor** (i.e., lower bound) of 0.5 (achieved by a simple greedy algorithm) [10] and the **hardness result** (i.e., upper bound) of 1 − 1/e ' 0.63 [11, 14] for the classical problem of the maximum matching in the semi-streaming model.

I cannot understand what is approximation factor...

Thanks!

Comment: I imagine it has something to do with graph streaming, whatever that is. Perhaps if you edit the question to say what paper you were reading (authors, title, journal name, date, etc.), possibly also give that information about reference [1] as well, someone might recognize the topic. It may also be worth considering whether to migrate the question to mathoverflow.net.

Comment: The approximation factor is just a bound on the ratio between the approximating algorithm's value and the optimal value.  Since this is a maximum matching problem, a factor of 0.5 means that the approximation algorithm can find a matching that is at least 50% as large as the maximum possible matching.  The hardness result is that it is hard in some sense (say NP-hard) to achieve >64% of the maximum matching in every instance.